# Installing Ubuntu 16.04 LTS on eMMC storage

Tags: system-installation, 16.04, laptop, acer, emmc

I'm experiencing a problem installing Ubuntu on my new laptop.
It originally had windows 10 Home version, but I wiped out the disk (eMMC) and tried to install the Ubuntu. However, I believe the storage type is not suitable for Ubuntu... I've lost Windows 10 and am unable to install any OS, which makes the laptop useless.

I want to install Ubuntu. The laptop I'm trying to install is  Acer Aspire One Cloudbook 14.

Comment: If you go into the BIOS / Set-up (accessible on boot with a key, eg. F12), is there any "Legacy boot" option ? If so, enable it.

Comment: You can install Ubuntu on eMMC (or I would not be typing this now from Ubuntu).

Answer (score 0):

Just give it  try: Go to bios
Disable CSM( Compatibility support Module)
Boot again in UEFI mode.
CSM is there to support older os'es. This will solve most of issues like  I/O Errors. Hope this helps..